# Trajectory Required to Hit Target with Newtonian Drag

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile, computational-physics, drag

I'm trying to write a function to determine the trajectory angle of a projectile, `theta`, from the horizontal required to hit a specified target location.

Inputs: Initial Position `(x0, y0)`, Final Position `(xf, yf)`, and Initial Speed `v0`

Output: Trajectory Angle `theta`

The challenge is that I want to use Newtonian [drag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_%28physics%29), i.e. `Fd = 1/2 * roh * Cd * Ac * v^2`, which introduces a non-linearity. As far as I know, this means that you can't construct an analytical solution. I understand how to calculate the trajectory numerically given an input angle and speed, but I'm not sure how to solve for the final position.

I've found:

(1) [Trajectory of a particle on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile#Trajectory_of_a_projectile_with_air_resistance), which shows how to find a trajectory path but not solve for the final position, and

(2) [this Phys.SE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/127973/), which talks about root-finding with algorithms like the [secant method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method), but I don't know if I can apply this method because of the non-linear `v^2` term.

Is there any elegant way to tackle this problem other than a brute force, guess and check approach? I can think of implementing a binary search kind of guess and check method to increase efficiency, but that's still not great.

Comment: 2D quadratic drag was also considered in [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28931/2451) Phys.SE post and links therein.

Comment: Microsoft Excel has an add-in called Solver than can provide a trial-and-error solution.  Do you have an equation or set of equations for your problem?

Comment: @DavidWhite, I understand that there are ways to solve this via trial-and-error. My question asks if there is a solution that doesn't involve trial-and-error.